# CallBack и AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-asynctask, callback

Лайаут `MainActivity` состоит из корневого `RelativeLayout`, в котором лежит `ProgressBar(VISIBLE)` и `FrameLayout(INVISIBLE)`. Сразу же в MainACtivity я открываю фрагмент:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new MyFragment()).commit();
```

Не буду выкладывать весь код, но в классе фрагмента у меня есть вложенный класс `AsyncTask`, который берет некую информацию в нэте. Соответственно на эту задачу тратится определенное время.
Я хочу, чтобы как только `AsyncTask` закончил свою работу, выполнилось следующее:

```
progressbar.setVisible(GONE);
frameLayout.setVisible(Visible);
```

По логике я понимаю,что цепочка должна быть такой: на экране прогрессбар - асинктаск делает свою задачу  - прогрессбар исчезает, появляется фрагмент.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать это через CallBack! Читаю инфу в нэте, смотрю примеры, но вообще не понимаю, как это в коде прописать. Если не затруднит, напишите данные куски кода, где в каком месте создать интерфейс, где какие методы вызывать и тд.

Comment: `AsyncTask` умеет все из того, что вы написали, никаких специальных колбэков не надо. Изучите любой туториал по `AsyncTask` и делайте.

Comment: А зачем Вы размещаете прогресс бар в разметке активити? Почему бы не управлять видимостью **содержимого** фрагмента (а не контейнера, где размещается фрагмент)?

Comment: @post_zeew т.е. мне в разметке фрагмента поместить в корневой RelativeLayout видимый ProgressBar и невидимый RecyclerView, а потом после завершения AsyncTask поменять их видимость?

Comment: @post_zeew я не понимаю, почему я люблю усложнять себе жизнь. Но ваш пример работает исправно. Решение более, чем простейшее. Но все равно огромное спасибо за наставления :)